# SQL to select rows distributed over time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a bit over a million timestamped rows, is there a way for me to select like 30 rows which are evenly distributed?

So that if my data table contains five rows and I need three I want row 1, 3 and 5 returned.

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Edit:
More specifically, I have a table with a list of different URLs and another table where data about the URLs are fetched and stored with regular intervals (in my case hourly).

What I want to do is be able to fetch a limited number of data rows (in my case 30) with an even interval between the dates. In a sense I want to filter out data points at a dynamic interval.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Please add table structure, example data, expected output and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Are the timestamps on your table evenly distributed?

Comment: Basically distribution is a database administrative job which will be taken care when you insert the records. If you do insert with proper order by clause then your records will be evenly distributed. I dont understand your requirement clearly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you could consider something like this..

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+
```

Now let's say I wanted to return approximately 5 evenly distributed results from across this table...

```
SELECT x.i
  FROM ints x 
  JOIN ints y 
    ON y.i <= x.i 
 GROUP 
    BY i 
HAVING MOD(COUNT(y.i),ROUND((SELECT COUNT(*)/5 FROM ints),0)) = 0; -- where '5' equals the approximate number of results to be returned.
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 7 |
| 9 |
+---+
```

Note that at ca. 1m results, this solution is NOT going to scale well. Use variables for the ranking bit instead.