# SQL Server - Correlation with random values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, correlated-subquery

Simplified example of my situation:

I have a table with three columns: `ID`, `CATEGORY`, and `TIMESTAMP`. Each `ID` and `TIMESTAMP` is unique, but `CATEGORY` is not unique.

I made this query to return a pseudo-random list of rows in the table (one per `CATEGORY`).

```
SELECT b.*
FROM
(
  SELECT MIN(RAND(ID)*100000-FLOOR(RAND(ID)*100000)) [RandomID] -- Select random identifier for each row
  FROM MYTABLE
  GROUP BY CATEGORY
) a
INNER JOIN
MYTABLE b
ON a.RandomID = (RAND(b.ID)*100000-FLOOR(RAND(b.ID)*100000))
```

It seems to be working fine, but my concern is that it is possible for two (or more) different `ID`'s to correspond to the same `RandomID`. If this happens, then the query would return inaccurate results, since the tables are being `JOIN`ed based on the `RandomID`.

Is this a valid concern? If so, how can it be overcome?

---

P.S. Some context:

In my case, the result of this query will be used to either keep or purge some records and files on a monthly basis, so the accuracy of the query result is very important.

To be clear, it doesn't matter to me *which* rows are selected, as long as there is guaranteed to be one for each `CATEGORY`, with one condition: I want the selected rows to be "roughly" evenly distributed based on `TIMESTAMP`. This is why I am correlating the data from random values rather than from the `TIMESTAMP`. (E.g. correlating via `MIN(TIMESTAMP)` would result in a higher density of rows at the beginning of the month.) Considering I have thousands of categories per month, picking the rows pseudo-randomly should generally lead to evenly distributed `TIMESTAMPS` (which is my goal).

One more note: I want the query to be *repeatable* (i.e. I want it to always select the same pseudo-random values.) Therefore, solutions involving things such as `newid()` are not adequate.

---

As requested, here is sample data.

```
TIMESTAMP       | ID | CATEGORY
-------------------------------
10/21/19 1:00AM | 1  | A
10/21/19 2:00AM | 2  | B
10/21/19 3:00AM | 3  | A
10/21/19 4:00AM | 4  | B
10/21/19 5:00AM | 5  | A
10/21/19 6:00AM | 6  | B
```

One possible output (depends on exactly what `RAND()` chooses) is:

```
TIMESTAMP       | ID | CATEGORY
-------------------------------
10/21/19 3:00AM | 3  | A
10/21/19 6:00AM | 6  | B
```

It doesn't particularly matter which rows are chosen, as long as there is one for each category. Again, I don't want to correlate based on `TIMESTAMP` because this guarantees that I would choose the first two rows in the sample data, but I want to have the `TIMESTAMPS` roughly evenly distributed.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to do.  However, you probably are not aware that each call to `rand()` produces the same value on every row.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `RAND()` with no arguments returns the same result to every row, yes, but I am passing a unique `ID` as an argument which returns a different result to every row (or "almost certainly different" - this is the reason for the question). I also multiply by a large number then only keep the decimal part to "further randomize" the selected random number.

Comment: If it's datetime, you could select based on the minimum microsecond.  This may or may not produce a good enough distribution depending on any idiosyncrasies in the data input.

Comment: @avery_larry My data has no millisecond (or microsecond) component. But even if it did, I still would have the same problem. If you are correlating based on the microsecond component of a timestamp only, then there is no guarantee that the results would be accurate, because it is possible that two (or more) rows have timestamps with the same microsecond component.

Comment: Then you can double up?  Find the single row with minimum second AND minimum ID?  Unless ID is sequentially correlated to timestamp.  What about using `newid()` instead of `rand()` ??  It is considered to be sufficiently non-duplicatable.

Comment: You can look at this link for some additional ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468988/sql-to-select-rows-distributed-over-time

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added sample data and desired results.

Comment: @avery_larry `newid()` is not usable here because there is no way to "get back" the original value chosen in the subquery. The only way to use `newid()` here would be to use a temporary table which I don't really want to do, but maybe it is necessary, e.g. `SELECT *,newid() [newRandomID] INTO #temp FROM MYTABLE` then do all operations on temporary table and correlate based on `newRandomID`.

Comment: row_number() over (partition by category order by newid()) rown ... where rown = 1

Comment: @avery_larry Please post full answer. Not clear to me only showing part of the query. If it works I will upvote and accept.

Comment: (i) `RAND` returns same value for each row in result (ii) `RAND(n)` will return same value for same `n` no matter how many times it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance can be a problem with this method.

```
declare @mytable table (timestamp datetime, ID int, category varchar(150))

insert into @mytable
values ('10/21/19 1:00AM', 1, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 2:00AM', 2, 'B'),
    ('10/21/19 3:00AM', 3, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 4:00AM', 4, 'B'),
    ('10/21/19 5:00AM', 5, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 6:00AM', 6, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 7:00AM', 7, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 8:00AM', 8, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 9:00AM', 9, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 10:00AM', 10, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 11:00AM', 11, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 12:00AM', 12, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 1:00PM', 13, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 2:00PM', 14, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 3:00PM', 15, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 4:00PM', 16, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 5:00PM', 17, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 6:00PM', 18, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 7:00PM', 19, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 8:00PM', 20, 'A'),
    ('10/21/19 6:00PM', 21, 'B')

select timestamp, id, category
from (
   select *, row_number() over (partition by category order by newid()) rown
   from @mytable
) a
where rown=1
```

I think you could also use your random code.  I don't know how the 2 methods would compare for distribution. **EDIT** I added ID to the order.  This makes the result repeatable even in the (very) unlikely event that the random code has a collision.

```
...
select timestamp, id, category
from (
   select *, row_number() over (partition by category order by RAND(ID)*100000-FLOOR(RAND(ID)*100000),ID) rown
   from @mytable
) a
where rown=1
```

Comment: Actually I just realized, `newid()` won't work because I want this result to be repeatable. Since `newid()` gets something new each time it is called, this won't work. Still, good answer. +1

Comment: The second query in the answer is repeatable.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 I added ID to the order by in my second query.  This should be repeatable INCLUDING the very small possibility of a collision in the RAND code.  Note, *of course*, that new data in the table will change the results.

Comment: Yes understood of course that the results will change if the data changes. Small possibility of collision in RAND code is still a possible issue though.

Comment: All of the queries I've had eliminate collisions.  The updated second query **also** eliminates collisions in a consistently repeatable way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question.  It is just that your approach doesn't seem promising.

`rand()` in SQL Server is not particularly good with sequential ids.  Consider this code:

```
 select id, floor(RAND(ID)*100000)
 from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) v(id);
```

It returns:

```
id  (No column name)
1   71359
2   71361
3   71362
4   71364
5   71366
6   71368
7   71370
8   71372
9   71374
```

([Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d76cdd4f20f013c9e81f8bc1fea6029) is a db<>fiddle.)

These are not exactly duplicates.  But they are not most people's version of "random" either.  I asked what you are really trying to do, because there might be solution to your problem.  Your question, though, does not clearly explain the purpose of the code.

Comment: Please take a closer look at my question. I am not selecting `FLOOR(RAND(ID)*100000)`. I am selecting `(RAND(ID)*100000)-FLOOR(RAND(ID)*100000)`. Like you point out, small changes to inputs of `RAND` doesn't actually change the output that much. This is why I multiplied by a large number and kept only the fractional part, to "further randomize" it.

Answer (score 0):

(Answering my own question)

After a couple of hours, I came up with a kinda strange solution, but it solves the problem as listed in the question.

The solution is to concatenate the randomly-generated number with the ID, then after the aggregate function occurs, strip out the part of the string containing the random number in order to get back the original ID, i.e.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM
(
  SELECT
  MIN(
    RIGHT(
     CAST(
      CAST(
       RAND(ID)                   -- 1. Get pseudo-random number   (e.g. 0.01234)
      AS decimal(10,10))          -- 2. Get 10 decimal places      (e.g. 0.0123456789)
     AS varchar(20)),             -- 3. Cast it to varchar         (e.g. '0.0123456789')
    4)                            -- 4. Get only the last 4 digits (e.g. '6789')
   + '_' + CAST(ID as varchar(3)) -- 5. Append underscore and ID   (e.g. '6789_1')
  ) [RandomID]
  FROM MYTABLE
  GROUP BY CATEGORY
) a
INNER JOIN
MYTABLE b ON b.ID = 
CAST(SUBSTRING(a.RandomID,6,100) as int) -- Strip away first 5 chars to get ID back
```

This solves the problem of both:

1. Selecting pseudo-random rows with `GROUP BY CATEGORY`
2. Guarantees that the `ID` in the `JOIN` correlates back to the original `ID` corresponding to the `RandomID`.